# Database structure design

Tags: database, relational-database

What is industrial best practice for bill to and ship to address tables?  Do people combine them into 1 table or seperate them into 2 different tables?  This is for general invoice.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have a `CustomerAddress` table allowing multiple entries per Customer. An `IsShippingAddress` flag would indicate which one is the shipping address. An `IsBillingAddress` column. would be used similarly.

This way the same address could be used for both shipping and billing if desired.

Comment: Or multiple shipping addresses could be allowed for each customer.  e.g. work and home.

Comment: Programming logic wise, does that add alot of overhead?

Comment: @gavin No, I would say it is less work than using separate tables for each.

Comment: I think adding 2 boolean flags would generally be less overhead than having 2 separate tables potentially with the many of the same data in each. Using one table and flags, you could set one address to be one or both of a shipping and a billing address for a customer.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen many systems with separate tables for permission and security reasons and sometimes there are many shipping addresses so a table for that is made. And also the confirmation phone, etc. You get the idea?